# How to (re-)name a pod in a K8s deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I want to deploy two containers in a pod through a deployment. But I want the pod to have exactly the name `yoda`. But in my case, a random string is always append after `yoda` like that `yoda-f8bcb7bf4-khml6`. Is it possible to force the pod name? I try the following but I did not get what I expected.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: yoda
  name: yoda
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yoda
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: yoda
      labels:
        app: yoda
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: anakin
        resources: {}
      - image: nginx
        name: obiwan
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Regards,
Benoît

Comment: Appended string is used for rollbacks as far as I know. This question has more detailed explanation about the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489128/why-do-pod-names-have-5-random-alphanumeric-characters-appended-to-their-name-wh

Comment: @begarco : Can you modify your Yaml as per this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865910/19230181) in this they are able to change the name of the Pod.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you expect but with Kubernetes pods should not be seen as [pets](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-treat-your-kubernetes-clusters-like-cattle-not-pets/), i. e. they should not receive a lot of attention but considered as highly replaceable. The name generation is part of this consideration among others to avoid conflicts.

Almost all ways of Kubernetes involve a kind of decoupling, including container rollouts. If a pod always receives the same name it cuts itself from things like rolling deployment strategies, in which on pod terminates while another spawns. Alternatively a conflict would be the alternative.

Without a deeper discussion **why** the pod should be maintained by hand I am not sure you will find a proper solution.

To give some perspective:

Labels (which you already use) give a good way to select a certain pod. If you change the deployment with a different image there might be two pods be selectable with your `yoda` label.

So, if you want to select either the older or the newer pod (but not both), adding another label with the respective version could solve the distinguishing problem (if that is what you want). See the template metadata section below.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: yoda
  name: yoda
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yoda
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      name: yoda
      labels:
        app: yoda
        app.version: 2.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: anakin
        resources: {}
      - image: nginx
        name: obiwan
        resources: {}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if statefulset can solve your issue. But the statefulset always retain pod name.How ever it also append a numeric number(start from 0) after the pod name & goes upto no of replicas you define in the yaml definition file.

For example, if you define the replica count to 3 in statefulset definition yaml file, then pod's name will be listed below.

[podName]-0

[podName]-1

[podName]-2